# How to delete obstacles (corduroy road) from DEM in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-10.3, hydrology

I have a DEM which looks like this:

[image]

The narrow longish lift running from north to south is a corduroy road (hope this is the correct word for "planks which allow people to cross a mire without getting their feet wet"):

[image]

The water can flow beneath the corduroy road without any problems in real life. Unfortunately GIS isn't aware of that because it is included in the DEM. This leads to wrong calculation of flow accumulations...

[image]

...and watersheds:

[image]

**How can I modify the DEM to not include the wooden corduroy road anymore? Is there a way to adapt this area to the elevation of the surrounding cells?**

Comment: This is similar to edge or noise removal. You may try Majority Filter or in Image Analysis, under Processing, try different low pass filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by user Nir led me to the "**Nibble**" tool (Spatial Analyst Tools - Generalization). I had to do some preparations before I could use it and also some postprocessing.

This is the model which works for me:

[image]

This is the resulting DEM without the obstacle:

[image]

And this are the watersheds and flow accumulations:

[image]